# How to determine if this function is one-to-one, onto, or bijection?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have a function $f_2: \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z $ defined by $f_2(m,n)=m^2+n$.

> How do I know if it is one-to-one, onto or both?

What I am most confused about is what $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ means and how that is different from just $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$.

I know one-to-one means every $x$ has a unique $y$ and onto means for all $y$, there exists an $x$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: Your explanation of one-to-one is very misleading (I cannot make out if you understood the definition of the term or not). A function $f: X \to Y$ is one-to-one if $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$ for all $x_1, x_2 \in X$.  You can think of it as: distinct $x$'s in $X$ are mapped to distinct images in $Y$.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. You made it much clearer though, thanks!

Comment: For one-to-one, informally, you could say that for any $y$, there is **at most** one $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This notation means that the "x" in your function is a pair of integers $(m,n)$.

So the question is: Do you know two pairs $(m_1,n_1)$ and $(m_2,n_2)$ of integers that give the same $m_1^2+n_1=m_2^2+n_2$?

The two pairs count as distinct if at least one element changes.

1. one-to-one?

Choose two different $m$s and try to find $n$s such that the image of the function is the same for the two pairs.

1. onto?

Try $m=0$.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  So does that mean it will be onto?  I'm not sure how to actually prove which one it is.

Answer (score 1):

For "onto" you need to answer this:  Given any integer $y$, can you find a pair $(m,n)$ so that $m^2+n = y$?

Comment: `m = 0`, `n = y` -- so yes. therefore it is onto.